# Ruby: Each IO stream in the output array argument causes IO.select not to wait.

Tags: ruby

I have a Linux machine (IP: 10.0.0.33), in which I run netcat as a listener on port 4444. I also have a Windows 10 machine that I connect to the Linux machine with the TCPSocket class.

I wrote a code in order to help me understand how IO.select works with the socket object and the IO objects STDIN and STDOUT, but I just can't figure this out.

Here is my code:

```
require 'socket'

socket = TCPSocket.open("10.0.0.33", 4444)
while true
    IO.select([socket], nil, nil) #I'm changing the arguments in this line

    puts(1)
    socket.gets.chomp
    puts(2)

    sleep(1)
end
```

As I expected, if I run the above code nothing happens until I send a message from the Linux machine. When I do, the 1 and 2 are printed, and then again nothing happens until I send another message from Linux (as I expected).

But, if I change only the IO.select line to

```
IO.select(nil, [socket], nil)
```

The 1 is printed immediately, and I don't understand why.

If I cahnge this line to anyone of the following:

```
IO.select(nil, [STDIN], nil)

IO.select(nil, [STDOUT], nil)

IO.select([STDOUT], nil, nil)
```

The 1 is printed immediately.

Why everytime I put something in the output array argument of the IO.select function, IO.select doesn't wait? 
I thought it should find an IO stream with some data ready to be sent through, but I send nothing in this program.

Also, why putting STDOUT in the input array argument of the IO.select function behaves the same way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with IO.select, but the documentation here shows that the arguments are read_array, write_array, error_array, timeout. If you nil out the read array and move your socket to the write array, you end up immediately doing a puts because there is nothing to wait for. Or at least, that's my understanding from the documentation. Theoretically with your socket in the second position, you could actually push data back into the socket from Ruby. https://apidock.com/ruby/IO/select/class